# Interesting proof of Liouvilles theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f$ be entire. Compute
$$F(R)=\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz, \space a \neq b \in \mathbb{C}.$$
This splits into three cases:
\begin{align}
     &(1)\, R \in (0,\min\{\vert a \vert, \vert b \vert\})\\
     &(2)\, R \in (\min\{\vert a \vert,\vert b \vert\}, \max\{\vert a \vert, \vert b \vert\})\\
     &(3)\, R \in (\max\{\vert a \vert,\vert b \vert\}, \infty)\\
\end{align}
For (1), the integral becomes zero as the winding number is zero thus
$$F(R)=0.$$
For (2), WLOG say that $$\vert a \vert < \vert b \vert,$$
then we have that the winding number about $a$ is 1 and we obtain the residue at $z=a$:
$$F(R)=2 \pi i \frac{f(a)}{a-b}.$$
Lastly, for (3) we calculate the residues at $z=a$ and $z=b$:
$$F(R)=2 \pi i \bigg(\frac{f(a)}{a-b}+\frac{f(b)}{b-a}\bigg)$$

Using this I am supposed to prove Liouville's Theorem which states if $f$ is entire and bounded then its constant.

So the either case when I differentiate Both sides I obtain
$$\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}=0$$

And so long as $a,b \neq 0$ I get that $f(z)=0$ which for $z \in B_1(0)$ and $f$ is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ thus entire and I proved it is $0$ and thus constant on the ball. But I haven't shown its constant on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: okay, thats what I thought , that I did not need to consider $a=0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring and that was to short hand things, I defined that integral as $F(z)$. As the imtnegral is dependent on $z$

Comment: Ah, you're right, correction will bee made.

Comment: @BrianMoehring is the rest correct?

Comment: No, the whole last paragraph is meaningless (about the derivative).  You just need to consider $R > \max\{|a|, |b|\}$ using the residue theorem (which you've already done), and then use the $ML$ inequality with $R \to \infty$ (which you haven't done yet) to conclude $f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: @BrianMoehring other than using it to prove Liouville's Theorem, I was good up till when I considered case (3) I am not finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of Liouville's theorem just involves looking at $\displaystyle\lim_{R\to\infty} F(R)$ in two ways:

- By the residue theorem, since $f$ is entire, for $R > \max\{|a|,|b|\},$ $$F(R) = \int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}\,dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{f(a)}{a-b}+\frac{f(b)}{b-a}\right) = \frac{2\pi i}{a-b}(f(a) - f(b)),$$ so that $$\lim_{R\to\infty} F(R) = \frac{2\pi i}{a-b}(f(a)-f(b))$$
- By the $ML$-inequality, since $f$ is bounded, for $R > \max\{|a|, |b|\},$ $$|F(R)| \leq 2\pi R \frac{\sup |f|}{(R-|a|)(R-|b|)} = (2\pi \sup |f|)\frac{R}{(R-|a|)(R-|b|)},$$ and $$\lim_{R\to\infty} (2\pi \sup |f|) \frac{R}{(R-|a|)(R-|b|)} = 0 \qquad \implies \qquad \lim_{R\to\infty}F(R) = 0.$$

It follows that $\frac{2\pi i}{a-b}(f(a)-f(b)) = 0$ so $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: So I was almost there just needed to hit it with the ML estimate for thee case $R \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: and since $f(a)=f(b)$ we have that $f$ is constant.

Comment: and how do we know $f$ is bounded, cause its integral is bounded?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Liouville's theorem is "Every *bounded* entire function is constant".

Comment: ahh you're right, brain fart!